# Only allow page.save_screenshot if a window exists?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara

My Capybara tests are designed to call `page.save_screenshot` if an example fails. This is configured in a `config.after(:each)` block in my `spec_helper`.

However, not all of my tests always have a window open. Long story short, some of my tests may make a few requests using `rest-client` and then pass/fail based on some `rspec expectations`. When these type of tests fail, a browser window opens because of the call to `page.save_screenshot`.

Is there a way to add a conditional so that saving a screenshot is only attempted when there is a window (headless or non-headless) open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probable do something like

```
page.save_screenshot if page.current_window.exists?
```

however the best options would really be to make tests that don't use the browser a different type of test (not system or feature) or add metadata to the test so that metadata can be used to determine whether or not the test uses the browser

```
# In your tests
it 'does something not using the browser', :no_browser do
   ...
end

# In your spec_helper
config.after(:each) do |example|
  page.save_screenshot unless example.metadata[:no_browser]
end
```

Comment: `page.current_windows.exists?` seems to always return true because calling this seems to invoke a browser window on its own.